# syntax error, unexpected '$factory' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTI ON) or const (T_CONST)

Tags: laravel, faker

currently i m using laravel 8.17.*

i m trying to to add data using faker library but given error  "syntax error, unexpected '$factory' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)" Help me to solve this error

ProductFactory.php

```
<?php

  namespace Database\Factories;

  use App\Models\Model\Product;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
  use Illuminate\Support\Str;
  use Faker\Generator as Faker;
  
   class ProductFactory extends Factory
   {
     /**
       * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
       *
       * @var string
       */
       protected $model =  \App\Models\Model\Product::class;

       /**
         * Define the model's default state.
         *
         * @return array

      public function definition()
      {
       return [
        //
       ];
      } */


     $factory->define(App\Models\Model\Product::class,function(Faker $faker){
    return [
        'name'=>$this->$faker->Word,
        'detail'=>$this->$faker->paragraph,
        'price'=>$this->$faker->numberBetween(99,999),
        'stock'=>$this->$faker->randomDigit,
        'discount'=>$this->$faker->numberBetween(2,30)
    ];
 });
}
```

**[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvZND.png

Comment: That code does not compile. You cannot call methods in a class outside a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 8 introduces class based model factories so the sample definition must be  like

```
<?php

  namespace Database\Factories;

  use App\Models\Model\Product;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
  use Illuminate\Support\Str;
  use Faker\Generator as Faker;
  
   class ProductFactory extends Factory
   {
        /**
         * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
         protected $model =  \App\Models\Model\Product::class;

        /**
         * Define the model's default state.
         *
         * @return array
         */

        public function definition()
        {
            return [
                'name'=>$this->faker->Word,
                'detail'=>$this->faker->paragraph,
                'price'=>$this->faker->numberBetween(99,999),
                'stock'=>$this->faker->randomDigit,
                'discount'=>$this->faker->numberBetween(2,30)
            ];
        }
    }
```

Comment: If downvoting pls care to state the reason for downvote. OP 's error can be resolved by rectifying the class definition as per the answer - so why the downvote

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you sometimes get downvotes on questions that are asking about a syntax error, as those should be (and in this case has been) closed as such. There's nothing wrong with your answer, but flagging/voting to close is the preferred response to this type of question.

Comment: @TimLewis thanks for explaining will keep that in mind. I always thought the SO is place where even ones just starting to code can seek help and most of the times just starters would be facing issues with syntax errors.

Comment: No worries :) Keep doing what you're doing; I'm seeing a lot of helpful answers from you, and your upvoted answers far outweigh your downvoted ones. Don't let a single downvote bother you too much, but yeah, just be aware that they tend to be more common on these types of questions. Cheers!